# How to properly detect rows to be swapped in a Gaussian elimination?

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, computational-complexity, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to describe an algorithm for solving solvable linear systems. The Gaussian elimination is pretty straightforward in terms of adding multiples of rows. However, consider the following example:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} 2x-3y+4z-5t  = 1 \\ 4x-6y+5z+1t = 3 \\ 1x+3y-2z+2t = 2 \\ 7x-1y+3z-5t = 10 \end{array} \right.$$

The straightforward algorithm will transform the second row into:

$$ 0x-0y-3z-9t = 1 $$

which will mislead the rest of the execution.

A simple swap between the second and third rows would solve that. That happens because $ 4/2 =  -6/-3 $, thus the second row is not well placed. In algorithmic terms, the first solution that crossed my mind was:

Let $A[i][j]$ denote the coefficient at the ith row, jth column.

1. The pivot of the ith row is $A[i][i]$
2. The element $A[j][i], j > i,$ will be turned into zero based on the $A[j][i]/A[i][i]$ ratio
3. This will lead to a correct result if, and only if, the ratio $A[j][i+1] / A[i][i+1] $ is different from the previous ratio
4. Therefore, for each row j and each column k, I must check if $A[j][k] / A[k][k] = A[j][k+1] / A[k][k+1] $ and, then, swap rows properly

It looks bad and expensive. Is there a smarter way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

----- EDIT

I'm not sure if the check can be done on-the-fly. Consider a matrix, that in the last step, looks like:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} ... \\ 0x + 0y + 0z + 0a + 0b + 1c + 4d = 3 \\ 0x + 0y + 0z + 0a + 0b + 2c + 8d = 5 \end{array} \right.$$...

The last variable will not produce the correct result. I may be saying something inaccurate though

Comment: Don't know anything much about computational complexity, but can't you just do the row subtraction anyway, then do the row swap afterwards if you have a zero in an "inappropriate" place?

Comment: I'm finding some of the language confusing here. What do you mean by "mislead the rest of the execution"?

Comment: @TheoBendit I meant that the result will be incorrect.

Comment: @David and if it the error occurs in the last row?

Comment: @user137227 Not sure what you mean - this "error" involves two rows being the wrong way round, so it can't occur only "in the last row", it must be in the last row together with the second last (or perhaps earlier) row, I would have thought.

Comment: @David I editted  it to explain better what I meant

Comment: Sorry to do this again, but I'm now not sure what you mean by "incorrect". Performing any of the elementary row operations to any row(s) in any order (so long as it's done one at a time) will never change the solution set. You can't introduce or destroy solutions. So, the question shouldn't be, which operations are "incorrect" to use, but rather, which operations should I use in order to get the matrix to (possibly reduced) row-echelon form in an efficient, methodical way.

Comment: In the example you have added, you can continue to row-reduce in the usual way (the last row minus $2$ times the second-last).  In this case you will get $0x+\cdots+0d=-1$: this is impossible and indicates that the equations you started with have no (simultaneous) solution.

Comment: You're correct, it makes no sense to have this situation. I guess that checking on-the-fly is a apparently better suited solution